# Undone Discourage search engines from indexing this site Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a undevelopment website so I have checked "Discourage search engines from indexing" of Wordpress which was working fine.

But since the site went live weeks ago. I forgot to un-check it so I just did 2 days ago but still nothing be found in google search engine. Please help me.

UPDATED - still not working.

I really need my live site to appear in google search result, please help me if you have experienced.

Things that I did:

```
  - Submitted site map to google.
  - Check there's no "noindex" in the page.
  - Requested Indexing the site in google search console account.
  - Integrated with YOAST SEO....
  - I have checked the robots.txt file.
```

Please give me advice. Thanks

Comment: Ask Google to recrawl your site https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Hi Andrew, thanks for suggestion, I did connect to Google search console. Add url to fetch then request index but nothing happens.

Comment: Try this next then https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35256?hl=en